# How Can I Properly Handle Concurrency Issue on Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous

**Scenario & Suggested Code**

There are multiple endpoints sharing similar logic (i.e, doing common task).

```
let express = require('express');
let router = express.Router();
router.post('/test1', function(req, res) {
   asyncFunction(something1, function(result) {
      var userId = result;
      ... some task
   });
};
router.post('/test2', function(req, res) { 
  asyncFunction(something1, function(result) {
      var userId = result;
      ... some task
   });
};
router.post('/test3', function(req, res) { 
   asyncFunction(something1, function(result) {
      var userId = result;
      ... some task
   });
}
```

As different endpoints need to do similar task (which include asynchronous call), I thought it might be possible to make a function in global scope, and callback the result and respond at the end.
So, it would be this:

```
let express = require('express');
let router = express.Router();
router.post('/test1', function(req, res) {
   asyncFunction(something1, function(result) {
      var userId = result;
      test123Function(userId, something, function(rst) {...})
   });
};
router.post('/test2', function(req, res) { 
  asyncFunction(something2, function(result) {
      var userId = result;
      test123Function(userId, something, function(rst) {...})
   });
};
router.post('/test3', function(req, res) { 
   asyncFunction(something1, function(result) {
      var userId = result;
      test123Function(userId, something, function(rst) {...})
   });
}
test123Function(userId, parameter, callback) {
   ...
}
```

**Question**

However, I understand that it is bad practice to do something on global space, and also, I worry about concurrency issue when I use the above structure. (For example, the response might be mixed up, when hundreds of people access to test1 at the same time, or multiple people access to test1 and test2 or test3 concurrently.)

I know that each req is unique, and therefore I can save some variable inside of req to avoid the above problem, but I cannot access to req from function in global space (specifically, when I want to use one function to handle similar task like the above). I also heard about session, but I am not sure if it would be the right concept to handle this case.

Comment: `const test123Function = ....` instead of using global scope?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Could you explain more how I can explore with const? I thought I do not gain any benefit from using const in this case.

Comment: This isn't browser-side JavaScript. Your function is locked within a module, it's not going to pollute the global space. You can also make a separate module with your logic. As for the concurrency issues - there is no such thing unless you actually use concurrent code (thread pool or multiple processes). If not, your code is guaranteed to execute in sequence, you just don't know when and in what order.

Comment: Then, it looks like the result would not be mixed up whether or not how many nested async functions are inside test123Function and there was callback after such operations. Am I right? I will study more about concurrent code for sure.

Comment: No, they will never get mixed up.
Don't bother investigating concurrency on node.js unless you really need it. It's a rather exotic subject, and with very limited use cases. For the vast majority of uses, asynchronicity over a single thread is perfectly enough. If concurrency is a must for you, it's possible you'd be better off switching from Node.js to Go.

Comment: @James when you do something like this in nodejs `HELLO='hello'`, node adds `HELLO` variable to global scope. But when you use `const/let/var` the variable is scope for module only. Take a look at your `let`s above on a page. All these variable is used within this module and it is not accessible outside of it.